# How programmatically change textblock margin inside listbox W8/WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8

as I'm new to Windows Phone application, facing this problem, It will be helpful if someone suggest their valuable answer. I have 2 `TextBlock` in grid inside `ListBox`. But I need programmatically change margin of second textblock because if app run in bigger screen second textblock is bad aligned. First textblock should be aligned to left second textblock should be aligned to right but when I set in in textblock is not working so I need change margin.

Image here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40039421/Untitled-1.png

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
    <ListBox x:Name="lbToday" FontSize="13" Tapped="lbToday_Tapped"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTodaySubjectName" Foreground="#FF02416C"
                               Text="Aplikovana inforatika" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Margin="0,0,75,0" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbSubjectHourStart" Foreground="#FF02416C" Text="10:30"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please suggest the way you want to display the text box by uploading a image. its not getting clear by your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem by making your inner grid with 2 columns and have each `TextBox` in its own column. That way you won't need to change anything at runtime and the layout should just work.

```xml
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: thx Alaa Masoud its the perfect solution, also FunksMaName thank you for your willingness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're not using MVVM, as this would be ideal for this sort of scenario, from what I understand in your question, you want programatically change the margin of the textblock when it is bound.

You can use a converter for this or just bind to codebehind property.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbSubjectHourStart" Margin={Binding ControlMargin} Foreground="#FF02416C" Text="10:30"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="0,0,0,0" />
```

In your code behind page constructor, set the data context

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
    }
```

You should probably also set the flag for the screen size once

```
//This should be changed to reflect your detection code
private bool isBigScreen = true;
```

Set your binding margin property, which is of a System.Windows.Thickness type

```
public System.Windows.Thickness ControlMargin
    {
        get
        {
            return isBigScreen ? new  System.Windows.Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10) : new System.Windows.Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
        }
    }
```

let us know if you want the converter way,